# Python list comprehension for csv file row extraction not evaluating correctly

Tags: python, list, csv

I am reading a csv file in Python 2.7. I want to extract a row from the csv file whenever the first 'x' characters match any entry specified in a list.

Here is some working code I use right now:

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'rb+') as infile:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'wb+') as outfile:
        searchValues = ['26:42:','1559:10935:','3345:26259:','4897:36651:','4909:36919:']
        for row in infile:
            for x in searchValues:
                if row[0:len(x)] == x:
                    outfile.write(row)
```

I wanted to simplify with a list comprehension. Unfortunately, I could not get it to work. Here is what I tried:

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'rb+') as infile:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'wb+') as outfile:
        searchValues = ['26:42:','1559:10935:','3345:26259:','4897:36651:','4909:36919:']
        for row in infile:
##            for x in searchValues:
##                if row[0:len(x)] == x:
            if [row[0:len(x)] == x for x in searchValues]:
                    outfile.write(row)
```

The list comprehension version runs without error. But the output file is a direct copy of the nput file, so the filtering check (list comprehension line) is not working. Please help identify the error.

Comment: Are you always searching on the first two values in a colon-delimited string?

Comment: @HughBothwell - yes, but only for the current implementation. It is possible that future uses of the script would not follow this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close! Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check if any of those list items is true. Also, you should use `startswith` to improve readability. Finally, with Python 2.7+, you can combine the two `with` statements:

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'rb+') as infile, open('output_file.txt', 'wb+') as outfile:
    searchValues = ['26:42:','1559:10935:','3345:26259:','4897:36651:','4909:36919:']
    for row in infile:
        if any(row.startswith(x) for x in searchValues):
            outfile.write(row)
```

The reason your list comprehension does not work is because If none of the prefixes apply, each value in the list if `False`, but since [a non-empty list evaluates to `True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), the condition is still fulfiled.

Just for completeness: You could also use `if [i for i in s if row.startswith(i)]`; this will create an empty list if none of the search values is a prefix to the row, which then evaluates to `False`.

However, using `any` is both more readable and should also be faster.

Comment: thanks for the response. I really appreciate the explanation of why my approach did not work. And your solution will work really well for me. I am especially grateful you took the time to show me some new tricks regarding `startswith` and double `open` on the same line. Reading the documentation, it seems I can further optimize by defining searchValues as a tuple, and passing that directly to `startswith` (avoiding explicit use of `any` and the `for` expansion).

Comment: Nice trick, [passing a tuple to startswith](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith). I did not know this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution with list comprehension

```
searchValues = ['26:42:','1559:10935:','3345:26259:','4897:36651:','4909:36919:']
with open('input_file.txt', 'rb+') as infile:
    with open('output_file.txt', 'wb+') as outfile:
        [outfile.write(row) for row in infile for x in searchValues if row.startswith(x)]
```

I am not sure why you want to do with list comprehension. Pythonic way to do is

```
from contextlib import nested

searchValues = ['26:42:','1559:10935:','3345:26259:','4897:36651:','4909:36919:']

with nested(open('input_file.txt', 'rb+'), open('output_file.txt', 'wb+')) as (infile, outfile):
     for row in infile:
         if any(row.startswith(x) for x in searchValues):
            outfile.write(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's simple - I wanted to use a list comprehension because I am an amateur and was unaware of the better approaches. Thanks for educating me on a more Pythonic approach!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that your search key is always the first two colon-delimited items in a string; so your code could become:

```
INPUT = "input_file.txt"
OUTPUT = "output_file.txt"

# set of key values to match
search_keys = {'26:42:','1559:10935:','3345:26259:','4897:36651:','4909:36919:'}

def get_key(s, num=2, delimiter=":"):
    try:
        last = -1
        for i in range(num):
            last = s.index(delimiter, last+1)
        return s[:last+1]
    except ValueError:
        return None

def main():
    with open(INPUT) as infile, open(OUTPUT, "w") as outfile:
        for row in infile:
            if get_key(row) in search_keys:
                outfile.write(row)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Note that this is O(file_rows), where the others are O(file_rows * search_items).

This will work for any criterion for which you can look at the string and know what the search key would be; just rewrite get_key() appropriately.

Comment: I really appreciate the response, and especially the focus on performance. My current file is not so big that this will make a huge difference (~200,000 rows), so I think I will use one of the shorter approaches. But this will definitely be handy in the event of bigger files to be searched.